# Executing the contents of a memo on a TADOQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a really long list of sql commands on a memo, when I try to execute it I get the following error:

**Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.**

The code to execute it:

```
Query.SQL.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text;
Query.ExecSQL;
```

I have a vague idea that the error is caused due to the way the query content was added, so, here's how I'm doing it now:

1) *Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('Patch.sql');*

2) *Proceed to the query commands*

As you can see, the contents of the memo is loaded from a file. Is there any other way to successfully do this?

P.S.: I'm using Microsoft SQL 2008.

Thank you!

Comment: You could quite easily determine whether the memo control is relevant to the problem by omitting it entirely: `Query.SQL.LoadFromFile('Patch.sql')`. Do you still get the same error? If so, then your SQL is bad. If not, then there's something about the memo.

Comment: I hope this is some kind of internal developer tool with limited exposure because this sounds like an SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not using parameters, so set `ParamCheck` off

```
Query.ParamCheck := false;
```

If there is a colon ":" in a string in the SQL, the TADOQuery thinks it's a parameter